# Implementing a custom Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I have a `MyUserControl` that contains a Label `label`, and a BO `public Person Person {get;set;}`.

I want that the Person's `Name` be always bind to the `label` like this:

(`"Name: {0}", person.Name`), in case if `person != null`
and
(`"Name: {0}", "(none)"`), in case if `person == null`

more than that, if the person name is changed, the label automatically update it.

is there a possibility for such a *binding*?

"Dirty" variant:

```
private void label_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label.Content = string.Format("Name: {0}", _Person == null ? 
                                                      "(none)" : _Person.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Name, FallbackValue='(none)'}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

This doesn't use a Label, but it accomplishes the goal.

---

If it needs to be a Label, you can do this:

```
    <Label Content="{Binding Person.Name, FallbackValue='(none)'}" 
           ContentStringFormat="Name: {0}"/>
```

One caveat with both approaches is that the text will also display `Name: (none)` if the binding is incorrect (Person == null is equivalent behavior to no property Person found).

Comment: should `Person.Name` in your case implement INotifyPropertyChanged or stuff like this?

Comment: @serhio, if you want to update when Name changes, yes, Person should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Also, if you want to update when Person changes, then the class containing the Person property should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged and notify when Person changes.  This binding will update when either Person or Person.Name changes.

Comment: I didn't know about FallbackValue either. It's certainly a nicer solution then the value converter.

Comment: I have one little problem setting `ContentStringFormat="{0} is the name"`... I am forced to use a space between " and {

Comment: @serhio, that's probably because the initial `{` is interpreted as starting a markup extension.  You can fix this by putting `{}` at the front of the string.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx

Comment: OK, finally, I am not in measure to change the BO class, so, the solution is very good, but not in my case. I suppose to deal with a "classic" BO class

Comment: @serhio, the underlying problem here is that your Model (Person) cannot provide rich notification for the WPF UI to consume.  The typical solution here is to create an intermediate object (a ViewModel) that handles all interactions between the UI and the Person, so that the data binding system has access to a rich, interactive view of the underlying data.  It's non-trivial architecting your application to support this pattern, but it's well worth experimenting with, as it can add a lot of value.

Comment: PS: is this binding still kept if the Person property is reset Person = null then Person = new Person?

Comment: I have a UControl "View" in which I have the Model Person. Don't know how to include there an intermediate. Because I change the Person properties in the PersonControl and this works like I expect.

Comment: @serhio, the comment chain is getting a bit long here; perhaps it would be valuable to open a new question with these additional inquiries?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by writing a value converter.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Person), typeof(String))]
public class PersonNameConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Person person = value as Person;
        if(person == null)
        {
            return "(none)";
        }
        else
        {
           return person.Name;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Once you have created this, you can add it as a resource in the XAML:

```
<local:PersonNameConverter x:Key="PersonNameConverter"/>
```

Then this can be included as one of the binding parameters

```
<TextBlock  
    Text="{Binding Path=ThePerson, Converter={StaticResource PersonNameConverter}}" 
    />
```

Comment: this is not about the "Name" property (NullorEmpty), but the Person one.

Comment: Is there restriction to the Person class? Should it implement INotifyPropetyChanged or stuff? because my BO classes are simple ones

Comment: is this binding still kept if the Person property is reset Person = null then Person = new Person?

Comment: If INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged for the person is fired, then the text would change. If the person doesn't change, but the name does, then the text wouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Use Binding FallBackValue property

```
        <Lable Content ="{Binding Person.Name, FallbackValue='(none)'}"/>
```